# What type of Italian visa should I apply for?

Tags: schengen-visas

I am an Indian citizen.  My daughter stays in Italy. I want to visit her for 30 days in September. What type of visa should I apply?

In the Italian schengen visa application form, there are two options to select.

1. Short term visa C .
2. Default _ Italy _India.

I am not able to understand which one should I apply for.

Comment: I wonder whether you've misunderstood the form.  "Default Italy India" does not appear to be a type of visa at all.

Comment: I think she meant "D" visa. Its for long term stay.

Comment: @AnishSheela that's certainly possible, and if it's correct then the answer is clear.  But how exactly do you get from "Default Italy India" to "D"?

Answer (score 3):

You have to apply for Short term visa "C".

This will enable you to visit Italy and other Schengen countries (provided, your main destination is Italy).